# Ito lemma and stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I need some help to solve a problem.
I have the following system of SDE:
[system of SDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp5DD.png)

I have to prove that $X_t^2 + Y_t^2 = (x^2 + y^2)e^t$

I have already shown with Ito lemma that $dZ_t=Z_tdt=(x^2+y^2)dt$ but I fail to integrate $dZ_t$ to have finally $Z_t=(x^2+y^2)e^t$.

Can you help me please?
Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Ian. But I think I am positive regarding the fact that $dZ_t=Z_tdt=(x^2+y^2)dt$ with $Z_t=X_t^2 + Y_t^2$

Comment: @bf93 : Your mistake is the following, in fact using Itô's lemma you should find out that : $dZ_t=Z_t.dt$, the solution of this deterministic ode is $C.e^t$ so using $Z_0=x^2+y^2$ you can identify $C$.  Best regards

Comment: Oh, now I see the misunderstanding: $dZ_t=Z_t dt = (X_t^2+Y_t^2) dt$, not $(x^2+y^2) dt$.

Comment: Many many many thanks for your help!!!! I have found the mistake.